# How to find Client OS using 'Mobile_Detect' Class

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using [Mobile_Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php) to find the `OS` used by the client, I tired this code

```
function get(){

   $user_agent = $this->mobile_detect->getUserAgent();

   foreach($this->mobile_detect->getOperatingSystems() as $os)
   {
        if(preg_match('/('.$os.')/i',$user_agent,$matches))
        {
            $dev = '';
            for($i=0;i<count($matches);$i++){ $dev.=$matches[$i];}
            $registration_os =  $dev;
        }
   }

    print_r($registration_os);


}
```

`$this->mobile_detect->getOperatingSystems()` returns the array

```
 Array
(
    [AndroidOS] => Android
    [BlackBerryOS] => blackberry|\bBB10\b|rim tablet os
    [PalmOS] => PalmOS|avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino
    [SymbianOS] => Symbian|SymbOS|Series60|Series40|SYB-[0-9]+|\bS60\b
    [WindowsMobileOS] => Windows CE.*(PPC|Smartphone|Mobile|[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3})|Window Mobile|Windows Phone [0-9.]+|WCE;
    [WindowsPhoneOS] => Windows Phone OS|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7
    [iOS] => \biPhone.*Mobile|\biPod|\biPad
    [MeeGoOS] => MeeGo
    [MaemoOS] => Maemo
    [JavaOS] => J2ME/|Java/|\bMIDP\b|\bCLDC\b
    [webOS] => webOS|hpwOS
    [badaOS] => \bBada\b
    [BREWOS] => BREW
)
```

But this is not working, any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this as you don't have any capture groups in your regex:

```
function get(){
    $user_agent = $this->mobile_detect->getUserAgent();

    foreach($this->mobile_detect->getOperatingSystems() as $os => $regex ){
        if( preg_match( '/(' . $regex . ')/i', $user_agent ) ) {
            $registration_os = $os;
            break;
        }
   }

   echo $registration_os;
}
```